# ClassNotFound when deploying in websphere

Tags: websphere, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I have build an ear file with the following content:

```
myear.ear
  - > META-INF
  - > mywar.war
```

The content of the war file is:

```
mywar.war
  - > META-INF
  - > WEB-INF
       - > classes
       - > jsp
       - > lib
            - > myjar.jar
       - > applicationContext.xml
       - > ....
```

where myjar.jar contains the class:

```
com.myapp.config.Configurator
```

Now when I deploy this war file in websphere 8.5.0.1 I get:

```
[11-04-13 10:16:54:875 CEST] 00000065 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement/CtxRootForWebMod.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[11-04-13 10:23:30:488 CEST] 00000062 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet resourceLoader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.config.Configurator (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:168)
    at com.myapp.web.servlet.WebResourceServlet.doPost(WebResourceServlet.java:60)
    at com.myapp.web.servlet.WebResourceServlet.doGet(WebResourceServlet.java:45)
```

Why do I get this error when the class in located in the ear archive?

Answer (score 2):

The error message also says "initialization failure".  A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` can be caused by an uncaught exception in a static initializer.  So the class file has been found but the execution of the `static` block failed.